# MS Access - Is there a limit to Public Functions/Routines in MS Access? RTE #7?

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have a number of forms (unbound) that load and save data through calls to class modules-Public Function save() & Public Function load(). I just got a brand new error today when trying to add another form, that shows up when the event handler fires to call the load. Run Time #7 "Out of Memory"...after reading MS Help it could be a number of suggestions they offer, however the one that pops out as the most applicable reason seems to be the "Too many Public Functions/Routine"....but I am not sure because I have never run into this before.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help guys!

Justin

Comment: Sounds like you've got recursion problems. Is something calling a function that ends up calling the original function? What's in your Save() and Load() functions (those are really not very good names for functions, seems to me). Also, your terminology is confusing -- are you using standalone class modules, or just plain old code modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much more likely that it is something that a form is doing.. such as a databound listbox that is loading a lot of data from another table.

Comment: If it's configured as an [out-of-control loop](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeprog/thread/a0608675-f437-4c7f-b9b2-37cd59c20acc), it could. Depends on the amount of custom code, I'd say. Without more specifics, it's hard to help him much.

Comment: But it's not the data that's causing the problem, but an issue in the code. And even then, you'd have to work hard to make it happen.